# Why does Ubuntu still use Python2 and what are the plans for eliminating it?

Tags: python

I haven't managed to find information on this.

Comment: Downvoting for seeming lack of research effort. Start with https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python

Comment: We don't use python 2. We use python 2.7 :) And how about https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3 ?

Comment: Upvoting, valid question that should have an answer on Ask Ubuntu. Is this not a dupe, though?

Comment: Agreed. It's a valid question, especially useful for developers to know which versions of Python are used and in which releases.  As for *why* I am pretty sure the answer is two words: *backward comparability*. Also avoiding breaking things. When you have an OS which is used on a lot of servers, data centers, and used as dev platform, well, removing a package at a whim breaks stability and pisses off a lot of devs and sysadmins

Answer (score 7):

You can look at [Python2 demotion (moving from main to universe) in progress](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2017-December/001234.html) for recent information. A couple of quotes from there:

> Python upstream announced the EOL of Python2 for 2020
>
> https://pythonclock.org/
>
> Getting Python2 demoted has been an ongoing task for several Ubuntu releases,
>   now finally having a desktop CD image in Ubuntu 17.10 which ships without a
>   Python2 interpreter.  The next step is to get Python2 demoted to universe,
>   before finally in the far future it can be removed entirely from the archive.

and

> ... you can find about 50 remaining issues at
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.tag=py2-demotion
>
> There are now about 35 left, so please consider working on these, or commenting
>   on solutions for some issue.
>
> It is unlikely that the demotion of Python2 will be possible for the 18.04 LTS
>   release, but please work on the issues so that we are ready for the demotion
>   once OpenStack is using Python3.